# What could go wrong if I don't use \detokenize when creating macro names using macro arguments?

Tags: macros, detokenize

I was in correspondence with the author of a LaTeX package in which I volunteered code similar to the following (I have anonymised it so that it is not obvious what package):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\savemacrostatewithname}[1]{%
    \expandafter\let%
        \csname saved@macro@state@named@#1\endcsname%
        \package@internal@macro%
}
\newcommand{\restoremacrostatewithname}[1]{%
    \ifcsname saved@macro@state@named@#1\endcsname%
    \else%
        \errmessage{Saved macro state named "#1" doesn't exist}%
    \fi%
    \expandafter\let%
        \expandafter\package@internal@macro%
        \csname saved@macro@state@named@#1\endcsname%
}
\makeatother
```

In their reply, one thing they said was that *instead of writing* `#1` *in your macros, you should write* `\detokenize{#1}`, *as it is safer*. Why is it safer? What might go wrong if I don't?

Comment: If you're sure that `#1` will always be replaced with a string of ASCII characters, there's no difference.

Comment: @egreg 'Sure' is a risky business ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright People who monkey with category codes are on their own.

Comment: @egreg User input can legitimately contain `~` or `_ ` with the `underscore` package loaded :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Let's say non TeX special characters, then; I don't consider `underscore` that creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have

```
\catcode`\!=\active
\def!{\hspace{2in} \fbox{boo} \hspace{2in}}
```

then `\csname foo!\endcsname` is an error as the name doesn't expand to a sequence of character tokens, but `\csname\detokenize{foo!}\endcsname`  is same as `\csname foo\string!\endcsname`  and makes the token with name `foo!`